# ASP.NET WebService - Object with Properties named ABC and ABCField

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services

I have an object with two properties 'ABC' and 'ABCField'. When this object is passed to an .NET application (.NET 3.5 CF) via a WebService a Reference.vb object is created on the client which declares the properties which access variables with the same name + 'Field'.

As a result I get

> Error 2   'abcField' is already declared as 'Private aBCField As
>   ABCOption' in this class.

```
  '''<remarks/>
    Public Property ABC() As ABCOption
        Get
            Return Me.aBCField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.aBCField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property ABCField() As String
        Get
            Return Me.aBCFieldField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.aBCFieldField = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

For compatibility reasons I would prefer not to rename or remove the properties in this object.

Is there a way arround this? Is there an attribute which can be set to change the name of the property as it is sent over the Web Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its funny how once you submit a question inspiration strikes.

I have used the  Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore() attribute in the object on the service side to hide the property 'ABC' from the client and created a new property called 'ABCProxy' property which gets and sets 'ABC'.